# Is there something like SelectedIndexChanged event handler for Datagridviewcomboboxcell in powershell?

Tags: powershell, winforms, datagridview, event-handling

I have a small datagrid with 2 comboboxcells and I want to detect when their index is greater than 0 to then enable a button. Problem is I can't find any information about this regarding powershell and I wanna avoid implementing C# because I don't know that language.

Is there something like `$combobox1.add_selectedindexchanged({})` for the comboboxcell?

Comment: You can probably handle the `CellValueChanged` event of your DGV and test the new value instead -- If the parent Form is short-lived (1), you could also handle the DGV's `EditingControlShowing` event, then remove-add an event handler to the `SelectedIndexChanged` or `SelectionChangeCommitted` events of the ComboBox instance passed in the EventArgs -- (1) *getting this wrong is easy*

Comment: Yes.  You can always search for c# code to use in you powershell script.  I often debug my powershell scripts in c# and then run in powershell.

Comment: @Jimi sounds like an idea , can you descrive to me how I can tell the eventhandler for CellValueChanged which cell should be checked? And what do you mean by '_if the parent Form is short lived_' ?